# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcassandra

Tags: c++, c, cassandra

I just installed the C/C++ driver for cassandra and trying to run the simple program from examples directory but

I am not able to resolve this error. /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcassandra

---

Here is my cassandra:

```
root@iWanUbuntu-1:~/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver/examples/simple# which cassandra
/usr/sbin/cassandra
```

---

Here is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6.4)

 set(PROJECT_NAME_STR cassandra)
 set(PROJECT_LIB_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME_STR})

 set(PROJECT_LIB_NAME_TARGET ${PROJECT_LIB_NAME})

 set(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR /root/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver)

 set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ".")
 set(PROJECT_EXAMPLE_NAME simple)

 file(GLOB EXAMPLE_SRC_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/examples/simple/*.c)

 include_directories(${INCLUDES})

 add_executable(${PROJECT_EXAMPLE_NAME} ${EXAMPLE_SRC_FILES})

 target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_EXAMPLE_NAME} ${PROJECT_LIB_NAME_TARGET} ${CASS_LIBS})

 set_property(TARGET ${PROJECT_EXAMPLE_NAME} APPEND PROPERTY COMPILE_FLAGS ${EXAMPLE_C_FLAGS})
```

---

Here is auto-generated make file commands:

```
 root@iWanUbuntu-1:~/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver/examples/simple# make --just-print

 /usr/bin/cmake -H/root/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver/examples/simple -B/root/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver/examples/simple --check-build-system 
CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0

/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /root/connect_cassandra_cpp    /cpp-driver/examples/simple/CMakeFiles /root/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver/examples/simple/CMakeFiles/progress.marks

make -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all

make -f CMakeFiles/simple.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/simple.dir/depend

cd /root/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver/examples/simple && /usr/bin/cmake -E 

cmake_depends "Unix Makefiles" /root/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver/examples/simple /root/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver/examples/simple 
/root/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver/examples/simple /root/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver/examples/simple /root/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver/examples/simple/CMakeFiles/simple.dir/DependInfo.cmake --color=

make -f CMakeFiles/simple.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/simple.dir/build
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_echo_color --switch= --red --bold "Linking C executable simple"

/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/simple.dir/link.txt --verbose=

/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /root/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver/examples/simple/CMakeFiles  1

echo "Built target simple"

/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_start /root/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver/examples/simple/CMakeFiles 0
___
```

Full Error Output:

```
root@iWanUbuntu-1:~/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver/examples/simple# make

-- Configuring done

-- Generating done

-- Build files have been written to: /root/connect_cassandra_cpp/cpp-driver/examples/simple

Linking C executable simple

/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcassandra

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

CMakeFiles/simple.dir/build.make:85: recipe for target 'simple' failed

make[2]: *** [simple] Error 1

CMakeFiles/Makefile2:60: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/simple.dir/all' failed

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/simple.dir/all] Error 2

Makefile:75: recipe for target 'all' failed

make: *** [all] Error 2enter code here
```

Edit to the question: Cassandra Installation Output:

```
    root@iWanUbuntu-1:~# sudo -E apt-get install cassandra
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    cassandra is already the newest version.
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
    fonts-dejavu-extra libatk-wrapper-java libatk-wrapper-java-jni libgif4 libgnomevfs2-0 libgnomevfs2-common libice-dev libntdb1 libpthread-stubs0-dev libsctp1 libsm-dev libx11-dev libx11-doc libxau-dev libxcb1-dev libxdmcp-dev libxt-dev lksctp-tools python-ntdb tzdata-java x11proto-core-dev x11proto-input dev    x11proto-kb-dev xorg-sgml-doctools xtrans-dev
    Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.

    root@iWanUbuntu-1:~# sudo -E apt-get install cassandra-devel
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package cassandra-devel
    root@iWanUbuntu-1:~#
```

Comment: I don't know this "library", but if it's under sbin and not preceeded by "lib" (e.g., libcassandra), it is an executable, not a library. If you are not sure, try "file /usr/sbin/cassandra". If it says "ELF 32-bit LSB executable" or similar, it is an executable. By the way, you can tell cmake to look for libraries with LINK_DIRECTORIES(dir/to/lib)

Comment: It is an executable. trying file /usr/sbin/cassandra gives output 
/usr/sbin/cassandra: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable. I am not sure which libraries it needs.

Comment: kamshi, consider that the line
ld: cannot find -l cassandra
suggests libcassandra.so as the ld program searches for lib+$libname+.so string within the lib folders, it's just it can't find this lib. 
 neelam, the file within /usr/sbin/cassandra is probably of course the shell script that starts the program, but when you try to compile a example it's the lib and the headers that you need, the program is usually just a 'client' if i may use such association. try install the devel part of the driver, usually this is the (very common) problem (on every linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking at the README of this project and it seems you cloned the Code section https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/master/README.md , but you'll need also the executables. Under the executables there is driver and driver-dev, and installing the driver-dev.deb package would get you the 1. header files 2. shared libs, which the compiler can't find. In general your compiler is telling you it can't find libcassandra.so within /usr/lib or usr/lib64 folders. This usually is when you install the driver, but forgot to install the driver-devel package. 
Here the devel package http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/ubuntu/
or if you installed cassandra with apt-get with something like

```
apt-get install cassandra
```

try get the devel part with

```
 apt-get install cassandra-devel
```

**EDIT:**

Eventually I've manually compiled and installed the driver from source and then compiled the examples/simple as the other solutions (intalling cassandra-cpp-driver.rpm) did not solved the whole thread. Just do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver.git
cd cpp-driver
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
cd ../examples/simple 
gcc simple.c -L /usr/local/lib64 -l cassandra -I /usr/local/include -o simple.o
```

Worked for me. On the other hand you could search for libcassandra.so.(some crazy extension) within /usr/lib64/ and cassandra.h within /usr/include . If there just make a symbolic link /usr/lib64/libcassandra.so  to /usr/lib64/libcassandra.so.(some crazy extension) and recompile

Comment: Miro, See Edits . I am getting E: Unable to locate package cassandra-devel. If I download dlevel package from your link which directory to copy to

Comment: Hi again, answer is updated how to get to compile the example. I see no reason not to work in this case, good luck

Comment: Thanks for your time. I was missing make install. It works now. I guess there is typo "make a symbolic link /usr/lib64/libcassandra.so to /usr/lib64/libcassandra.so."  exact same file?

Comment: no i meant 'make symbolic link from /usr/lib64/libcassandra.so to /usr/lib64/libcassandra.so.some.crazy.extension'  but the extension is in brackets instead of dots. first time i found the lib it was with name libcassandra.so.2.3.0 and it won't be found with such name (hence the link)